# stop socket.io emit if event occurs more than 3 times within 5 seconds

Tags: angularjs, socket.io

I am creating a sample chatting application using angularjs and socket.io, as I am new to socket, I am stuck at a functionality which I want to implement.

If user tries to send more than 3 messages in 5 seconds, block his messages from socket.io backend and show him a dialog in the app saying that he is spamming.

I am using angularjs ( i.e., angular 1) on front-end.

Comment: Try using `Date.now()` functionality to calculate with times/dates the user has sent the message.

Comment: can you provide a proper answer !!

Comment: There is also a package called `socket-anti-spam`. Seems like a very nice package. [see here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket-anti-spam).

Comment: The general topic of what you're talking about is "rate limiting".  There has been a lot written on the topic so a search will find you algorithms and code.